# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openshift.dynamic'; 'openshift' is not a package

Tags: python, dynamic, openshift, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to login to openshift from the following python script:

```
from kubernetes import client
from openshift.dynamic import DynamicClient
from openshift.helper.userpassauth import OCPLoginConfiguration
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass()

apihost = "api"
username = "username"
password = password

kubeConfig = OCPLoginConfiguration(ocp_username=username, ocp_password=password)
kubeConfig.host = apihost

kubeConfig.verify_ssl = True
kubeConfig.ssl_ca_cert = './ocp.pem' # use a certificate bundle for the TLS validation

kubeConfig.get_token()

print('Auth token: {0}'.format(kubeConfig.api_key))
print('Token expires: {0}'.format(kubeConfig.api_key_expires))
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
File "/home/python/Openshift/openshift.py", line 5, in
from openshift.dynamic import DynamicClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openshift.dynamic'; 'openshift' is not a package
```

I have already installed openshift package:

```
$ pip3 list | grep openshift
openshift               0.12.1
openshift-client        1.0.17
openshift-client-python 2.0.0


$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.7
```

Could someone please advise what's wrong with my code or package? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code can config the connection? I see nowhere the import for config. Try:

`from kubernetes import client, config`

Also install:

```
pip install openshift-client-python
```

Also with kubernetes I would also `import yaml`

as a first line in your code.